# About finding eigenvector for complex eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: Find the general solution of the system $y'=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 5 \\ -5 & -1 \end{pmatrix} y$

Attempt: The eigenvalues are $-1 \pm 5i$.

Then I let $v_1=(x_1,x_2)^T$ and plug $-1+5i$ into the original system.

$\begin{pmatrix} -5i & 5 \\ -5 & -5i  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

After row-reduction, I get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$x_1+x_2 i=0$, for $v_1$, the answer is $x_1=1$,$ x_2=i$. I am wondering whether I can choose $x_2=1$ and $x_1=-i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-i,1)$ and $(1,i)$ are just multiples of each other: $(-i,1)=-i (1,i)$. So either one is fine.

Comment: I see, that means I can choose any as free variables.